# How can read a file, split the strings in it, and write the output to a hashtable in C#?

Tags: c#, file, split, hashtable

I need to read file and split string into hash table in C#.

For example;

1231231 Hi this is the first entry / hi this is the second entry

Currently, I'm reading the lines in the files line by line using a `StreamReader`, and then I splitting every line to 3 different strings. For example, "1231231" to one string, then up to "/" sign to another string at last after "/" sign to another string.

1231231 will be the key of the hash table, and the others will be the values of the hash table. I'm stuck on this part.

Comment: Sounds like somebody is not doing homework again.

Comment: So the key is always a number at the start of the line, and you want a list of strings separated by / as the value?

Comment: I think that you need to clarify what you're trying to do. As stated, it appears that you want to have two entries in the hashtable, one with key = 1231231, value = "Hi this is the first entry" and the second with key = 1231231, value = "hi this is the second entry". This is not possible.

Comment: Amplifying on Jason's comment: the keys must be unique in a Hashtable.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, it sounds like you're actually trying to use one key and store two items against it. Hashtables have exactly one value per key, so either "Hi this is the first entry / hi this is the second entry" will be the value, or you need two keys, or you need to store a different data structure for the two values (a class with 2 string values, for example -- a Tuple, which is coming in .NET 4).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have fairly regular input set, you'll probably want to use a [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx) for this.

This pattern seems like what you want:

```
^(\d+)\s+([^/]+)\s+/\s+(.+)$
```

That would be:

- `^` : Anchor to start of string
- `(\d+)` : One or more digits
- `\s+` : 1 or more whitespace characters
- `([^/]+)` : 1 or more characters which do not equal '/'
- `\s+/\s+` : 1 or more whitespace characters plus 1 slash and 1 or more whitespace characters
- `(.+)` : 1 or more of any character
- `$` : Anchor to end of string

Comment: Regex is a beautiful beast :) Use it until performance becomes an issue, then rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Using Bobby's regex..

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
            string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"PATH\FILE.TXT");

            foreach (string line in fileLines)
            {
            var match =  Regex.Match(line, @"^(\d+)\s+([^/]+)\s+/\s+(.+)$");
            hashtable.Add(match.Groups[0].ToString(), new string[] { match.Groups[1].ToString(), match.Groups[2].ToString() });
            }
        }
```

The hashtable values are inserted as a string array since the key has to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Could be more optimal, but it'll work:

```
        char stringSplit = '/';
        char keySplit = ' ';
        Dictionary<string,string[]> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]>(1000);
        using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\somefile.txt"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                int keyIndex = line.IndexOf(keySplit);
                string key = line.Substring(0, keyIndex);
                string[] values = line.Substring(keyIndex + 1).Split(stringSplit);
                dictionary.Add(key,values);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code to add entries to the hashtable:

```
Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable(new EqualityComparer());
string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"somePath");
foreach (var fileLine in fileLines)
{
    int indexOfSpace = fileLine.IndexOf(' ');
    int indexOfSlash = fileLine.IndexOf('/');
    string keyString = fileLine.Remove(indexOfSpace);
    string firstValue = 
             fileLine.Substring(indexOfSpace, indexOfSlash - indexOfSpace - 1);
    string secondValue = fileLine.Substring(indexOfSlash + 1);
    hashtable.Add(new Key(keyString), firstValue);
    hashtable.Add(new Key(keyString), secondValue);
}
```

Key class to wrap same string:

```
public class Key
{
    private readonly string s;

    public Key(string s)
    {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public string KeyString
    {
        get { return s; }
    }
}
```

Equality comparer that supplies *GetHashCode* functionality in order to make two keys based on same string go to the same entry in hashtable:

```
public class EqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer
{
    public bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        return ReferenceEquals(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object obj)
    {
        return ((Key) obj).KeyString.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```